# Rx and Retrofit: Changing ServiceApi request parameter in request loop started by repeatwhen or repeatuntill

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I am using retrofit and RxJava for my application.
I am executing a request which will hit the server every 1 sec. For this, I create retrofit service API with request params and subscribe on the returned observable and use repeatWhen.

Problem is , every time the request is hit, I want to change the request parameter sent with the request(Basically have to make it dynamic). How can I achieve this?

For eg Use case: sendLocation Api sending currrent location to server every 10 sec. How can this be achive this using retrofit and RxJava

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@TassosBassoukos' answer works if you add the delay in.  Specifically, here is a full example using github API that alternates calls between two users. Make sure not to let this run too long --

```
public interface GitHubService {
    @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
    Observable<String> getRepo(@Path("user") String user);
}

static String[] users = {"octocat", "square"};
static int i = 0;

static String getUser() {
    return users[i++ % 2];
 }

public void RxGitRepo() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
      .client(client)
      .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
      .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
      .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
      .build();

   GitHubService gitHubService = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
   Observable
      .defer(() -> Observable.just(getUser()))
      .flatMap(user -> gitHubService.getRepo(user))
      .repeatWhen(done -> done.delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

For your use case, instead of polling the location every 10 seconds, you could set up your observable on the location and use that to trigger updates.  Using a library like [android-reactiveLocation](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation), you can get an `Observable` that streams locations.  Something along the lines of the following untested code --

```
LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create() 
                             .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                             .setInterval(10000);

ReactiveLocationProvider locationProvider = new ReactiveLocationProvider(context);
Subscription subscription = locationProvider.getUpdatedLocation(request)
    .sample(10, TimeUnits.SECONDS)
    .flatMap(/* your retrofit call based on the observed location */)  
    .subscribe(/* subsciber for retrofit call results */);
```

Comment: thanks iagreen. Wanted something generic for example tomorrow instead of location, I want to send some text data to the server in request param in say every 2 seconds and that text data is constantly changing so how can we achieve that. What I understand is we have to create a retrofit request by providing the request params and then subscribe to that observable returned by Service and then play on that.. So when I put it into loop how can I change the request param in the next tick

Comment: I see what you are saying, but you are reaching outside of the stream for additional data (the location, the changing text, etc.).  I would still wrap the changing event in an observable and let it drive the server requests -- that way the data we need to send is naturally coming in a stream.  It seems more natural to me, but see the edit for a more generic example of how you are trying to do it.

Comment: I did exactly similar to the first example you provided and that works.. Thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
    AtomicInteger requestParam = new AtomicInteger();

    apiCall.request(requestParam)
            .doOnNext(response -> requestParam.set(response.getRequestParam()))
            .repeatWhen(objectObservable -> objectObservable
                    .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .flatMap(o -> Observable.just(requestParam.get())
                    .takeWhile(integer -> /* condition */ )));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
Observable
.defer(() -> Observable.just(getLocation))
.flatMap(location -> doNetworkCall(location))
.repeatWhen(...)
```